# pandas.read_csv() can apply different date formats within the same column! Is it a known bug? How to fix it?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date

I have realised that, unless the format of a date column is declared explicitly or semi-explicitly (with dayfirst), **pandas can apply different date formats to the same column, when reading a csv file! One row could be dd/mm/yyyy and another row in the same column mm/dd/yyyy!**
Insane doesn't even come close to describing it! Is it a known bug?

To demonstrate: the script below creates a very simple table with the dates from January 1st to the 31st, in the dd/mm/yyyy format, saves it to a csv file, then reads back the csv.

I then use pandas.DatetimeIndex to extract the day.
Well, the day is 1 for the first 12 days (when month and day were both < 13), and 13 14 etc afterwards.  How on earth is this possible?

The only way I have found to fix this is to declare the date format, either explicitly or just with dayfirst=True. But it's a pain because it means I must declare the date format even when I import csv with the best-formatted dates ever! Is there a simpler way?

This happens to me with pandas 0.23.4 and Python 3.7.1 on Windows 10

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['day'] =np.arange(1,32)
df['day']=df['day'].apply(lambda x: "{:0>2d}".format(x)  )
df['month']='01'
df['year']='2018'
df['date']=df['day']+'/'+df['month']+'/'+df['year']
df.to_csv('mydates.csv', index=False)

#same results whether you use parse_dates or not
imp = pd.read_csv('mydates.csv',parse_dates=['date'])
imp['day extracted']=pd.DatetimeIndex(imp['date']).day
print(imp['day extracted'])
```

Comment: I have also come across this problem in the past, but I don't remember how I fixed. I believe it is worth raising an issue

Comment: This has apparently been a known issue for almost 3 years: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12585
I am speechless. Different date formats in the same field...

Comment: AFAIK the one and only way to fix this is to declare the date formats explicitly. See the discussion at: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12585#issuecomment-475942674 This is a HUGE issue which has the potential of having messed up years of work by tons of users.

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous: that's a very valuable self-answer, please write it and accept it. The bottom line is trying to infer dates and user date-formats is fallible. So specify the format explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

By default it assumes the American dateformat, and indeed switches mid-column without throwing an Error, if that fails. And though it breaks the Zen of Python by letting this Error pass silently, "Explicit is better than implicit". So if you know your data has an international format, you can use `dayfirst`

```
imp = pd.read_csv('mydates.csv', parse_dates=['date'], dayfirst=True)
```

With files you produce, be unambiguous by using an ISO 8601 format with a timezone designator.

Comment: I do not find this an insightful answer. It doesn't add anything, it doesn't explain how to solve the problem, it just minimises its importance.

Comment: I agree the bug is annoying, but I think this is an acceptable solution. As Chris mentions, you should always explicitly define the date format, otherwise you can have problems even with perfect data. A machine can only reliably guess that a date is of a certain format if there are dates with days > 12, which might not always be the case.